# Frequency decomposition of an mp3 file?

Tags: fourier-analysis, sound, frequency

After loading an `mp3` file

```
test = Import["test.mp3"]
```

I would like to make a plot with x-axis being the **frequency** of waveforms contained in `test`, and y-axis being the **average amplitude** of the respective frequency throughout the mp3 duration. Can I use Mathematica to do that?

Comment: should the x-axis be logarithmic ?

Comment: @andre I am mostly interested in voice frequencies, 300 - 3600 Hz, so logarithmic might be a bit crammed. But any solution would do, I would adjust the axes later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming we have three sine waves:

```
audio = Audio[Array[0.2*Sin[2 \[Pi] 3000 #] + 0.5*Sin[2 \[Pi] 5000 #] + 0.1 Sin[2 \[Pi] 7000 #] &, 44100, {0, 1}]]
Spectrogram@audio
```

View the Spectrogram you can verify it really have three sine waves.
[image]

`SpectrogramArray[audio]` do the same thing,the row is represent *time*,the column is represent *frequency*.

```
ListLogPlot[#[[;; Round[Length@#/2]]] &@Total@Abs@SpectrogramArray[audio], PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True,DataRange -> {0,QuantityMagnitude[AudioSampleRate@audio/2]}]
```

[image]

if you use *.mp3 file:

```
audio = Import["ExampleData/car.mp3"];
Spectrogram@audio
ListLogPlot[#[[;; Round[Length@#/2]]] &@Total@Abs@SpectrogramArray[audio], PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {0,QuantityMagnitude[AudioSampleRate@audio/2]}]
```

[image]

Also do fourier analysis in all audio data.

[image]

```
Periodogram[Flatten@AudioData[audio], 1024, 1024, BlackmanHarrisWindow, 
            SampleRate -> QuantityMagnitude@AudioSampleRate[audio], 
            Ticks -> {Range[0, 22000, 1000], Range[0, -160, -20]}, 
            TicksStyle -> Italic, AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
            AxesLabel -> {"Hz", "dB"}, ImageSize -> 900, 
            Background -> Black, PlotStyle -> Green, 
            AxesStyle -> White, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]